# angular firebase hosting is not working

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment

I am following [this tutorial](https://test-app-38199.firebaseapp.com/) to build angular app.
I created project on firebase and successfully deployed it.

```
i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: preparing dist/test-app directory for upload...
+  hosting: 7 files uploaded successfully
```

- Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/test-app-38199/overview
Hosting URL: https://test-app-38199.firebaseapp.com

My firebase.json is like this:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "dist/test-app",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "destination": "/index.html"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However in my browser all I see is this:

[image]

Comment: Why is `public` set up to `dist/test-app`, do you have several folders in your dist folder ?

Comment: Thanks for message. test-app is the name of my Angular app. When I do build command, the folder is generated as dist/test-app

Comment: If you didn't touch anything it should be in dist only.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue, Angular apps no longer are compatible with Firebase. I can host my angular app anywhere else and it runs fine, but when deployed into the public folder, the app won't run. It's almost as if Google is deliberately disabling Angular.